# How to do an "unless" conditional when changing permissions in a ruby_block in chef?

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

In chef I Have a `ruby_block` where I am changing permissions and ownership of a directory. How can I do a check where the permissions are only changed if they have not already been changed by the "      FileUtils.chown" statement?  I need to do this within the ruby_block if possible because i am ganna have other code in the ruby block. What would my "unless" statement be? Here is my code:

```ruby
  ruby_block 'exe' do
    block do
      FileUtils.chmod 0755, '/make/news'
      FileUtils.chown('root', 'root', '/make/news')
    end
  end
```

Comment: When used correctly, Chef's file and directory resources are already idempotent. Use them and save yourself some trouble!

Comment: Agree with @ToddA.Jacobs here. Prefer using Chef resources as long as there is one for your requirement. Adding "scripty" logic complicates the cookbook. You might want to update your question with "have other code in the ruby block". It will help in understanding your requirement for `ruby_block`.

Answer (score 3):

The correct way to do this is to use Chef's file resource:

```
file '/make/news' do
  mode 0755
  owner 'root'
  group 'root'
end
```

You're going down the road of trying to re-write the file resource which is not a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

### Using the Chef Resource's `not_if` Guard

Chef resources share a number of common functions. The [ruby_block](https://docs.chef.io/resources/ruby_block/) resource supports the [not_if](https://docs.chef.io/resource_common/#not_if-examples) property as a [conditional guard](https://docs.chef.io/resources/#common-functionality-guards). The general format is:

```
ruby_block 'custom chmod' do
  block do
    #
  end

  not_if { true }
end
```

So, you *could* program your logic this way, but it will eventually bite you badly. Chef often works better if you use a [file](https://docs.chef.io/resources/#file-resource) or [directory](https://docs.chef.io/resources/directory/) resource declaratively using a separate block to manage permissions, and then (if necessary) chain it with a notification from some other block that needs a given permission set. For example:

```
directory '/make/news' do
  mode  '0755'
  owner 'root'
  group 'root'
  action :nothing
end

ruby_block 'do something with news' do
  block do
    #
  end

  only_if { true }
  notifies :create, 'directory[/make/news]', :before
end
```

That said, the goal of configuration management is to continuously converge, so I'd strongly question whether creating this interdependency between resource blocks is truly necessary in the first place. If possible, just converge your directory permissions *every time* to enforce them. While this *may* create a sequencing dependency within your recipe, a more declarative approach often simplifies cookbook and recipe debugging in the long run. Your individual mileage may vary.